# Select within one day Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

In Full Calendar's week/day view, the flag `selectable` toggles the ability of clicking and dragging a block on the calendar. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/

However, I'm looking for ways to restrict the selection within the day when the clicking started.

I couldn't find anything related in the Full Calendar Doc, I'm wondering if anyone has some clever ideas over this.

Answer (score 0):

try using
[defaultAllDayEventDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultAllDayEventDuration/)